# How to edit /etc/fstab when system boots to read only file system?

Tags: ubuntu, fstab

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

I pasted something incorrect (from a tutorial) into my /etc/fstab file. As a result, the root file system will not mount when the machine boots up.

I know what needs to be fixed in /etc/fstab, but I cannot save the file (or any file) because the system boots as read only.

As root, I tried:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

to no avail. The error message cited the section of bad options that I pasted into /etc/fstab.

I read some stuff about booting into single user mode by adding 'single' to the end of the kernel parameter. I can't seem to find the kernel parameter. On the grub menu, I highlight Ubuntu and press 'e' which brings up a file with some sort of configuration, but there is no 'kernel' parameter to be found.

I'm relatively new to linux. Can anyone help me figure out a way to fix my /etc/fstab file so that Ubuntu will boot normally?

Comment: Can you make a live USB and boot to it? The kernel parameter is the line that begins with `linux ...`.

Comment: ah thanks for pointing out which is the kernel parameter. i will try to add 'single' to the end of it and follow instructions from there.

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /` should work. What are the exact error messages?

Comment: @Gilles - it worked after I booted into single user mode

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw / -U <uuid>` did it for me, where <uuid> is found in the output for `blkid`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get things back to where they should be, I:

1. Highlighted 'Ubuntu' at the boot menu
2. hit 'e' to edit the configuration
3. in the line starting with `linux=`, I switched the 'ro' to 'rw' and added the word 'single' at the very end of the line
4. hit f10 to boot
5. once it booted, as root, I did:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
6. as root, I edited /etc/fstab to get it where it needed to be
7. rebooted normally and everything seems to be fixed

Answer (score 31):

The way you have tried the `mount` command still uses the information from `/etc/fstab`.

Try the following version and it should work independent of the contents of `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb6 /
```

Note: Instead of /dev/sdb6, use whatever device is valid for your drive.

Comment: Thanks! I can now see my /etc/fstab. But now I see that nano and vi are not found.

Comment: Thank you. It's worth mentioning that you may need to run it with `sudo`